# Make iframe and video in iframe responsive

Tags: css, iframe, responsive

I am use PlusThis for video tracking and the code below works fine when viewing the desktop version of the site, however, when I use mobile the video is obviously not responsive.

In order to use the PlusThis feature, I need to use the code below and I can't figure out how to make it responsive:

```
<iframe id="vimeo_187396498" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/187388888" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    PTFeatureBase.setContactId('[memb_contact fields="Id"]');
    PTFeatureBase.setContactEmail('[memb_contact fields="Email"]');
    PTVideoTriggers.listen({
        type: "vimeo",
        playerId: "vimeo_187399998",
        feature: "1545-MHe1qQxtRTKCd4cTdB5aDcedYjgJORyfcidK6gv1",
        triggerType: "cue",
        times: [660]
    });
</script>
```

Could someone please show me how to make this code responsive while still keeping the JavaScript intact that I need in order to use features from PlusThis?

Answer (score 0):

```js
PTFeatureBase.setContactId('[memb_contact fields="Id"]');
   PTFeatureBase.setContactEmail('[memb_contact fields="Email"]');
   PTVideoTriggers.listen({
     type: "vimeo",
     playerId: "vimeo_187399998",
     feature: "1545-MHe1qQxtRTKCd4cTdB5aDcedYjgJORyfcidK6gv1",
     triggerType: "cue",
     times: [660]
   });
```

```css
iframe{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
 }
```

```html
<iframe id="vimeo_187396498" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/187388888" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="vimeo_187396498" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/187388888" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You used width and height inside iframe tag. So, Please take that iframe tag in a div area and use css iframe as div child. Please follow example below:
HTML code:

```
<div class="videoiframe">
<iframe id="vimeo_187396498" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/187388888" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.videoiframe iframe {width:100%; height: auto}
```

I hope, You got it.